# Teams bot: Updated message with a Card not properly displayed until chat is refreshed

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams bot running with node js. I can response with a Text message or a Card to an incoming message, and I can update a previously sent message with a new Text Message.

But I have a problem when I update a message with a Card. It is not displayed properly, I see this in the chat:

---

```
<URIObject type="SWIFT.1" url_thumbnail="https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https://neu1-urlp.secure.skypeassets.com/static/card-128x128.png">Card - access it on <a href="https://go.skype.com/cards.unsupported" title="https://go.skype.com/cards.unsupported" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">https://go.skype.com/cards.unsupported</a>. <Title>Card</Title><Swift b64="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"><Description></Description></Swift></URIObject>
```

---

But If I change the chat/channel and go back, it is properly displayed.

It happens the same in a private chat with the bot and in a channel, writing to the bot (@bot)

Why can it be this "painting" problem?

My testing code:

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {

...

//connectorClient, credentials, ...

...

        var activity = context.activity;
        var sConversationId = activity.conversation.id;

    // Send text message 1
        var message = MessageFactory.text("Text 1");
        var response = await connectorClient.conversations.sendToConversation(sConversationId, message);
        var sActivityId = response.id;

    // Update message 1 with a Card
        var jsonPath = __dirname + '/' + 'herocard_test.json';
        const jsonCard = require(jsonPath);
        var message2 = MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.adaptiveCard(jsonCard));
        message2.id = sActivityId;
        connectorClient.conversations.updateActivity(sConversationId, sActivityId, message2);
...
```

Thanks,

Diego

Answer (score 2):

@Diego Thanks for reaching out!! We could repro this and we have raised a bug for it. We are working on fixing this.

Comment: Any news on when this will be fixed or if there is a workaround? I am having the same problems as Diego when updating an activity. Switching views works, but that is not good enough for production.